# the marker is added after the second click state hasn't been updated with the newItem you added yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

markers on the map appear after the second click on the button.. why ? download data from api.In this.state.items, after clicking the button, data is placed ..

```
state = {
items:[]
}
handleFetch = () => {
    fetch('http://xxx)
      .then(resposne => {
        if (resposne.ok) {
          return resposne;
        }
        throw Error(resposne.status)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          items: data,
        }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }
  }
render() {
    <button onClick={this.handleFetch}>show markers</button>
    return (
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of your state it seems to be a class component.

The `for loop` should be called in a callback to wait for the items to be set before to loop over it because the fetch is asynchronous.

Here is the callback function:

```
const loopOverItems = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
          var obj = this.state.items[i];
          let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
          new mapboxgl.Marker()
            .setLngLat(myLatlng)
            .addTo(map);
        }
      }
```

and here is the last `then` where you set your items:

```
.then(data => this.setState({items: data}, loopOverItems));
```